# Include Javascript function in Haml form action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cookies, haml

I have a Haml form created as:

```
%form{:action => "/" + getCookie('city') + "/todo", :id => "CheckoutForm", :method => "post"}
```

the `getCookie(cookie_name)` function is the Javascript function to get a session cookie.

However, when I navigate to this page, I get this error: `undefined method 'getCookie'`

What I want to do is, determine the name of the URL that the browser is redirected to on submitting the form dynamically using session cookies.

In short, how can I add javascript in Haml form action?

I have no idea if this is the best way to do it or not, but I can't modify the form very much and have to get this working this way itself.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to set the `action` attribute through jQuery:

```
$('#CheckoutForm').attr('action', '/' + getCookie('city') + '/todo')
```

Comment: I tried this. On clicking the form's submit button, it just redirected me to the same page.